# ABP.io + NetTopologySuite = True?

Tags: entity-framework-core, abp, nettopologysuite, spatial-data

How to handle spatial data with abp.io framework (SQLServer and EF Core)? Any recommendations?

I guess one can have NetTopologySuite in the Domain project, but it does not feel DDD correct to do so.

Please tell me if you have any experiences with this combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abp Framework project are just a .Net Project. you can use the `NetTopologySuite` like you normally use in any other project. if you don't want DDD then just create a single layer project. single layer project removes all the DDD requirements.

Here is the more info about single layer project: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Todo/Single-Layer/Index?UI=MVC&DB=EF

Comment: Thanks Anto, I have started to use it as it is at a DDD project structure, and think it works. Still, I think I need to replace SQLite with LocalDb to get similar behavioural.